# How to refresh the display value of formControlName after its value is changed?

Tags: angular

I have two `formControl` inside a `formGroup` inside of a `formArray` like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="fg" (ngSubmit)="SaveInput()">
  <ul formArrayName="comments">
    <div *ngFor="let cm of fg.get('comments')['controls']">
      <input readonly formControlName="xts">
      <input type="text" formControlName="xtxt">
    </div>
  </ul>
</form>
```

When data from `xtxt` is saved in DB and returns a timestamp, I'd like to have this timestamp value displayed on `xts`. I'm able to set the value in two places and confirmed are good. But it's not reflected in display

```
SaveInput()
{
  ...
  this.mySvc.saveInput(param)
  .subscribe
  (
    good =>
    {
      let x =<FormGroup>this.fg.get(selectionString);
      x.value.xts = good.timestamp;  // <-- place 1
      x.controls.xts.value = good.timestamp; // <-- place 2
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't set value directly but use methods. I believe `patchValue` suits your case the best

Comment: @DPro Works!! Would you please post it as an Answer so I can accept it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't set value directly but use methods. I believe `patchValue` suits your case the best.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks to @D Pro, one place is good enough `x.controls['xts'].patchValue(good.timestamp);`